# How to get a formatted std::string in c++ without length liminations

Tags: c++, string, string-formatting

What is the best way (short, using standard libraries and easy to understand) to do this in c++:

```
std::string s = magic_command("%4.2f", 123.456f)
```

- without length limitations (char s[1000] = ...)
- where "%4.2f" is any c format string (which would be given to printf for example)

I am aware of the snprintf malloc combo suggested for pure c in

[writing formatted data of unknown length to a string (C programming)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854353/writing-formatted-data-of-unknown-length-to-a-string-c-programming)

but is there a better, less verbose, way to do this with c++?

I am also aware of the std::ostringstream method suggested in

[Convert float to std::string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125880/converting-a-float-to-stdstring-in-c)

but I want to pass a c format string such as "%4.2f", and I could not find a way to do this with ostringstream.

Comment: [Boost format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583976/sprintf-with-c-string-class/7584035#7584035) sounds like what you're after.

Comment: I can recommend Boost.Format, especially because it's templated. If you, for whatever reason, don't want to use it, there's also Poco::PatternFormatter: http://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/Poco.PatternFormatter.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New answer 10 years later: C++20 `std::format`**

Finally, this will be the superior choice once you can use it:

```
#include <format>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::format("{:4.3}\n{:4.3}\n", 3.1, 3.1415);
}
```

Expected output:

```
 3.1
3.14
```

This will therefore completely overcome the madness of modifying `std::cout` state.

The existing `fmt` library implements it for before it gets official support: https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt Install on Ubuntu 22.04:

```
sudo apt install libfmt-dev
```

Modify source to replace:

- `<format>` with `<fmt/core.h>`
- `std::format` to `fmt::format`

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include <fmt/core.h>

int main() {
    std::cout << fmt::format("{:4.3}\n{:4.3}\n", 3.1, 3.1415);
}
```

and compile and run with:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o main.out main.cpp -lfmt
./main.out
```

Output:

```
 3.1
3.14
```

**Old answer**

All answers given are good since there seems to be no really standard way of doing what I want, I'll vote you all up, and accept my own sum up course of action:

- if the string is short enough to estimate its size by hand, do it, multiply your estimative by 4, and allocate it statically.
- if you can get away with stringstream + setprecision, do it since it is standard
- if not, and you are willing to write and include a short helper function based on snprintf/check overflow/dynamic allocation, do it and put it into your project "utils" file
- finnally consider which dependency is less restrictive for your project (maybe you are already using one of them):

  - if boost is less restrictive, use Boost.Format
  - if GNU/BSD extensions are less restrictive, use asprintf

Answer (score 8):

You can try [Boost.Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/format/doc/format.html):

```
std::string s = boost::str(boost::format("%4.2f") % 123.456f);
```

It's not included in the standard, but Boost is about as standard as a non-standard library can get.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 5):

I would use a `std::stringstream` (in combination with `setprecision`) instead and use `.str()` afterwards to get the `std::string`.

Answer (score 5):

C++ completely abandons the concept of format string, so there will be no standard way to do it. You could implement `magic_command` yourself using `asprintf` (its `vasprintf` variant actually), though.

Note that `*asprintf` are GNU/BSD extensions. As such, they don't exist on Windows. Also, this solution is not type-safe, and will only accept POD types (so no classes, structs or unions).

```
std::string magic_command(const std::string& format, ...)
{
    char* ptr;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    vasprintf(&ptr, format.c_str(), args);
    va_end(args);

    std::unique_ptr<char, decltype(free)&> free_chars(ptr, free);
    return std::string(ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you literally want to use your syntax and forgo type safety, I'd write a little wrapper class that wraps `snprintf`. I'd make it start out with a local, automatic buffer of some small size (say 2048?) and call `snprintf` once. If it succeeds, return a `std::string` created from that buffer. If you overran, allocate a `std::string` of the correct size and repeat the `snprintf`.