# Modern way to provide formatted strings as arguments

Tags: c++, string, string-formatting

I have a question very similar to [std::string formatting like sprintf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342162/stdstring-formatting-like-sprintf) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12039647/how-to-get-a-formatted-stdstring-in-c-without-length-liminations) but these are very old so I dare to retry in order to collect some approaches.

I want to have a function/method which takes arguments which define a formatted string with some variables, much like `printf`/`sprintf`. For example it could be a method `send_string(ARGS)` which would format and send a string to some receiver. E.g.:

```
server->send_message("value1: %d, value2: %0.3f, value3: %s", 2, 3.14, "hello world");
```

I know the stream concept and I know `boost::format`. But I wonder what's the *least verbose* approach *without unnecessary dependencies*.

Here is what comes to my mind:

- use a **stream based approach** - result would look like:

  ```
  server->msg_out() << "value1: " << 2 
                    << ", value2: " << 3.14 
                    << ", value3: '" << "hello world" << "'";
  ```

  This look most plausible to me but it's very **verbose**, it's hard to see what the output would look like. Particularly when you try to try to achieve tabular output or special formatting for real values. On the plus side you don't have any dependencies.
- Use **C based variable arguments**. Would look like the example above which is well known and used a lot even though it's deprecated, error prone and inflexible.
- Use [Boost.Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/format/)

  ```
  server->send_message(boost::format(
              "value1: %d, value2: %0.3f, value3: %s") % 2 % 3.14 % "hello world"));
  ```

  or (to avoid dependencies in your API):

  ```
  server->send_message(
      boost::str(
          boost::format(
              "value1: %d, value2: %0.3f, value3: %s") % 2 % 3.14 % "hello world")));
  ```

  which seems to be the most `sprintf`-like C++ based approach. But I don't like this approach neither - it's very **slow**, it has a cruel syntax, it's very verbose, too and it introduces the dependency to Boost (if you don't use it already).

So currently I would decide in favor of the stream based approach but every time I use it I think to myself: there must be something more elegant!

Are there simpler approaches I didn't think of yet?

Comment: I think format specifiers in C++ are just unnecessary and bad. Look at how `std::cout` does it. Use templates. C++ is advanced enough to avoid type-unsafe stuff like this.

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15106102/how-to-use-c-stdostream-with-printf-like-formatting) is a slightly newer version of those old duplicates. It mentions [N3716](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3716.html), a proposal for the inclusion of a new `std::putf` function in the standard; but I don't think that proposal has been accepted into any future standard revision yet.

Comment: @cad The problem with io manipulators for formatting is that these don't fit well for internationalisation of output formats. You know, different formatting specifications may be needed, because words change their positions in different languages.

Comment: + it seems to be not trivial to implement a class which can be used for s.th. like `server->msg_out() << "my key: " << std::hex <<  key << std::endl`. Do you have a working example?

Comment: Frankly, I would just accept an `std::string`. Then the user can assemble however he wants.

Answer (score 3):

You might perhaps use, or take inspiration from, Qt [QString::arg](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#arg) functions; it has a format string with `%1` ... `%9`  but the arguments are given thru `arg` overloaded functions, e.g.

```
QString str;
long num;
double dbl;
QString outstr = 
 QString("str=%1 num=%2 dbl=%3").arg(str).arg(num).arg(dbl);
```

So the typing is by overloading `arg` but the format string is much more localization friendly.

Comment: When you already use Qt this is an option. The resulting command in my example would be `server->send_message(QString("value1: %d, value2: %0.3f, value3: '%s'").arg(2).arg(3.14).arg("hello world"));` which is acceptably verbose but of course you need to *qtify* your API..

Comment: As I said, you could also take inspiration from that approach